# Why publishing to IIS is change for ASP.net core ?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

When I publish under Visual Studio 2015 CTP 5 then I don't have to do setting for application pool CLR version.

Now for ASP.net core application and as per documentation (**http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html**)  we have to do setting for application pool clr to No managed code.

Why it is like that ?

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET Core applications no longer run inside IIS but run out-of-process and IIS acts only as a reverse proxy. This functionality is provided by the AspNetCoreModule which is a native IIS module. Since no managed code runs in the IIS process it is recommended to set application pool as "No managed code". 
I wrote a detailed blog post describing how ASP.NET Core applications are running with IIS. You can find it [here](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/).

Answer (score 0):

This is because ASP.NET Core runs as a plain old command line application outside of the IIS. Therefore, IIS is merely a pass-through to Kestrel, which is the ASP.NET Core web server which runs in it's own separate process. This platform is what provides the cross-platform capabilities of .NET Core.