# ASP.NET .Net Core IIS return 502 when request from extranet

Tags: asp.net-core

My published my asp.net core(Full Framework) site to the server running Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7 successfully.
When I try to visit it from my PC, it always returns 502 Bad GateWay, like this:
[Extranet visit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfDbS.png)
But when I visit it from the server, it works well.

I have noticed that the remote address is not right according to the picture, but I don't know how to fix it.

If you can help me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the address with the `UseUrls()` method for the `WebHostBuilder`.

I posted a related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134916/1271462).

Comment: The remote address is still 127.0.0.1 , after I use the UseUrls() Method.